# "RUN ./configure" => not found in Docker, after "RUN cd srcdir && chmod +x ./configure" succeeds

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to build swig inside of a Dockerfile. However, when I try to run `./configure`, I get an error saying it is not found, although it is definitely there.

Here is a working sample for swig installation using Dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:7.5-cudnn4-devel
MAINTAINER Tim O'Shea <tim.oshea753@gmail.com>
# install swig
RUN apt-get install -y g++
RUN apt-get install -y libpcre3 libpcre3-dev
RUN wget "http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/swig/swig-3.0.12.tar.gz"
RUN chmod 777 swig-3.0.12.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf swig-3.0.12.tar.gz
RUN cd swig-3.0.12 && chmod +x ./configure && ls -l
RUN ./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/swigtool
RUN make
RUN make install
```

Comment: how did you download swig ? are you using a zip or tar.gz ? it seems like an issue with the end of line style

Comment: I downloaded the tar.gz from sourceforge

Comment: Can you add the rest of your dockerfile so i can test it ? I have wrote a sample and it works correctly no issues for me

Comment: @MostafaHussein I've added the Dockerfile.

Comment: BTW, while you were indeed asked for the whole Dockerfile, what we *usually* ask for here (indeed, what the rules require) is a [mcve] -- the *shortest possible* code that can be run without changes to reproduce the same problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This would be my fault as i am was not clear enough regarding this, I have updated the original question

Comment: @MostafaHussein That's indeed much-improved! I hadn't voted on the question either way hitherto, but in this state it's worth a +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in these lines in specific:

```
RUN cd swig-3.0.12 && chmod +x ./configure && ls -l
RUN ./configure --prefix=$(pwd)/swigtool
```

Note that `RUN` works per layer only which means each time you have to use `RUN cd swig-3.0.12` so you may add them to one layer like this

```
RUN cd swig-3.0.12 && /configure --prefix="$PWD/swigtool" && make && make install
```

> The RUN instruction will execute any commands in a new layer on top of the current image and commit the results which explained in [RUN in Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run).

Alternatively you can add this before all commands that needs to be executed inside `swig-3.0.12` directory, for example:

```
WORKDIR /swig-3.0.12
RUN ./configure --prefix="$PWD/swigtool"
RUN make
RUN make install
```

Comment: As an aside, I'd suggest `$PWD` instead of `$(pwd)`, as in `--prefix="$PWD/swigtool"`; still depends only on POSIX-standardized functionality, but doesn't require `fork()`ing a subshell, so it's much faster to execute. (Not a difference here where it disappears in the overhead of a Docker `RUN` command, but it'd be a different story in a tight loop).

Comment: Of course using `$PWD` sounds way better! I have updated the answer, Thanks for your suggestion and explanation.